# how to display Trademark symbol in php?

Tags: php

I got a trouble regrading of I cannot display trademark symbol? 
what happen of my code ?

I had test this 2 code in the below, but still failed?

```
$textmsg = htmlspecialchars($textmsg);
file_put_contents($textpath, $textmsg);


preg_replace("™", "â„¢Â", $textmsg);
file_put_contents($textpath, $textmsg);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the right sequence you are trying to replace with.

Comment: Looks like an characterset/encoding issue.

Comment: What content encoding are you using?

Comment: That isn't a valid regex either, so [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) will be throwing errors.

Answer (score 9):

Try using the HTML entity `&trade;` which will display as ™. This applies for HTML and PHP equally. It also gets around issues with text encoding, which is what seems to be the issue for you, though without a bit more information it's hard to say exactly what.

If you are trying to output to a standard text file, then you are going to have to deal with your encoding issues. If this is the case, then you'll need to provide more information as these issues are often difficult to sort out and could even be your text editor and not your code.

Another potentially better solution if you are trying to fix user input is to make sure your server is sending a proper `Content-Type` HTTP header, **including a text encoding**. This will make almost all browsers send data using that encoding, which means it will then be displayed properly when output as well. For instance:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: display in php is no problem but when I want to read it back in the text file is the problem? how ?

Comment: @user723128 where is this file coming from? You need to be careful about text encodings, as far as I'm aware PHP only has decent support for UTF-8. If your file isn't UTF-8 then this is likely the source of your problems

Answer (score 1):

What if you use [htmlentities()](http://dk.php.net/htmlentities) instead of htmlspecialchars?